# Exception handlers on array C++

Tags: c++, exception

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

template<class T, int N>
void PrintArray(array<T, N> a) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < int(a.size()); i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << ' '; a[i] = 1 + i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    array <int, 6> arr = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 };
    PrintArray<int, 6>(arr);

    cout << "2a pos do arr -> ";
    cout << arr[2] << endl; 

    **cout << arr[7] << endl;**


    system("Pause");
    return 0;

}
```

I don't seem to be understanding how to use try catch to handle this exception, or if it is even possible (I believe it is). Can someone please explain how would I handle the non existent element of the array.

Comment: Start with `cout << arr.at(7) << endl;`

Comment: I tried cout << arr.at(7) << endl; and it returns :

Unhandled exception at 0x763F35D2 in Parte 4.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x004FF814.

Comment: So this I can catch?

Comment: You can catch the exception.  Or not.  Depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Well I was just experimenting to see if I could understand the use of the exception handling, so I will mess around with this case since it can be handled. Thank you very much

Comment: Most compilers (more precisely, standard library implementations) have a way to enable bounds checks for containers. I suggest looking into that.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing an array out of bounds (whether it is a `std::array` or a C-style array) using the `[]` operator is **undefined behavior**, there is no bounds checking performed, so there is no guarantee of an exception being thrown at all.  *Best case*, an OS exception will be thrown, which you may or may not be able to catch.  *Worse case*, no exception will be thrown at all and you will corrupt memory, which you may or may not notice for a long time if ever.

If you want to guarantee a standardized catchable exception is thrown, use the [`std::array::at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at) method, which throws a [`std::out_of_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) exception that you can catch with a standard C++ `try/catch` block, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <exception>
#include <cstdlib>

template<class T, int N>
void PrintArray(std::array<T, N> &a) 
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << a[i] << ' '; a[i] = 1 + i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::array <int, 6> arr = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 };
    PrintArray(arr);

    std::cout << "2a pos do arr -> ";
    std::cout << arr[2] << std::endl; 

    try {
        std::cout << arr.at(7) << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::out_of_range &) {
        std::cout << "range error!" << std::endl;
    }

    std::system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If you try to access an array index which is out of bounds your program will crash - you can't catch that. You just need to guard against it to make sure it cannot happen

EDIT - Of course the replies to this answer are valid, it is not guaranteed to crash. You may even be lucky and get an exception but that's unlikely so no point in trying to handle it.

BUT I stand by the answer - make sure it cannot happen. Theres so many ways to do this, runtime checks, use std::array and at() (with try/catch), ASSERTS the options are endless. It's much better to avoid situations happening through good design than to handle the situation when it has already happened.

Comment: *If you try to access an array index which is out of bounds your program will crash* That's onle possible outcome, it is by no means guaranteed to happen

Comment: No, "will crash" is wrong. It's undefined behavior. It _might_ crash (if you're lucky). It might also print random garbage, format your hard drive, or make your cat pregnant.